# What should a candidate avoid asking an interviewer?

Tags: interviewing

It is normal for an applicant to ask questions to an interviewer.

But can an applicant ask questions such as, "How many applicants do you expect to have?" or "How many interviews do you have today?" I think these questions are irrelevant if the job isn't managerial in nature.

Should an applicant ask this? If so, what questions should an applicant definitely avoid?

Comment: @RichardSaysReinstateMonica Why?

Comment: I disagree. There are some answers (such as "we don't give sick pay" or "a maximum of two weeks vacation") that would rule a company out from serious consideration. Better not to waste people's time.

Comment: @DJClayworth those questions make the hiring managers think that you're more interested in the benefits/time off than anything else, esp sick time.

Comment: @DJClayworth I'd go one further - those are things I'd want to ascertain *before* even going for an interview.

Comment: @berry120 That's often tricky to do. Companies rarely publish their benefits packages.

Comment: @RichardSaysReinstateMonica A good company recognizes that an appropriate amount of time off, and pay when sick, is good for the employee and the company. Unless you buy into the whole ultracapitalist thing that everybody should sacrifice their health and their family time for the benefit of the company.

Comment: @DJClayworth that's a false dilemma, and a strawman.  The interview is not the time or place to ask.  Nothing more sinister than that.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Yes, I agree...but does neediness disqualify a candidate from the next step in the process (such as a second interview)? Especially if the applicant is qualified, such as passing the interview? i.e. the applicant asks these questions after the interview, via e-mail or as the applicant is leaving.

Comment: *Companies rarely publish their benefits packages.* @DJClayworth Which makes the hand wringing over applicants wanting to know all the more ridiculous. They created this problem by not this information (with actual numbers, not the word "generous") in the job ad or at least in the Careers section of their web site.

Comment: @JossieCalderon, In the scheme of things, it probably doesn't matter that much, but personally, I would only ask that question once I got the job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Always have a few questions ready to ask - it shows you have an interest in the company or role.

Avoid asking questions about the salary, how much holidays or sick leave you would be entitled to or how often you will be required to work late. Those kind of questions suggest a lack of interest/enthusiasm for the role and a less than stellar work ethic.  While these are clearly important factors in deciding if you want to work for the organisation, this isn't the time to ask them. Instead, wait until they make an offer - at that point it's part of the remuneration negotiation process rather than the interview stage.

The sort of questions you should ask are...

**Questions about the role/company**

- If I'm successful, what would be the most important thing for me to get to grips with in the first 6 months?
- Can you describe a typical day in the life of a...
- What is your biggest challenge at present?
- Do you see X (some current talking point - blockchain, brexit, global warming) affecting how you do business?  (This obviously needs to be relevant to the company and industry)
- Is there scope for me to grow this role and take on more responsibility?
- How would you describe the culture?
- Do you like working here?
- Will any travel be required...

**Questions about the interview process itself**

- What are the next steps?
  = How many more rounds will there be?
- When could I expect to hear back from you?
- Have you many more people to see?

And I always ask "Do you have any concerns about my candidacy that I could address for you before we wrap up?". Reason being, I once got feedback from an interview that they didn't think I was interested in the job. I was actually really excited at the thought of taking it on but the interview was after hours and I'd just done a full day chasing my tail because everything was falling down around our ears - I was exhausted.

Comment: (This was in answer to a query about the value of asking how many other candidates there are - that's been deleted but I'll leave this here). It's close enough to a nothing question - but it helps build a rapport with the interviewer (a kind of "how was the weekend" for somebody you know nothing about) and it will also determine how long it will be before you can expect feedback. Interviewers will rarely answer with just a number - they'll say something like "a few tomorrow and then 1 on Friday" or "we're seeing people until the middle of next week - and there are still CVs coming in."

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if you want a list of things, here are some good things I would never ask and these might not be as obvious as you think:

#### 1) Personal questions unless it's related to their career or if they bring up their own personal life.

This may be obvious but I believe it would be very strange to ask them about their personal lives. However, if you're asking them what inspired them to be what they are today, that would be fine. In fact, psychology indicates that people love to talk about themselves and things that give them a lot of passion.

#### 2) "What does this company do? What are the requirements for this job?"

If you ask what the company provides and what they need from you, then you haven't done your homework on reading the company's mission or the job posting.

#### 3) "What are the other candidates like?"

You should never worry about other people. Only focus on you and your qualifications.

#### 4) "How often will I get a raise and/or bonuses?"

This might give the indication that you're not really interested in the company's culture.

#### 5) "If I don't get the job, can you send my résumé to other different organizations within the company?"

Don't be a freeloader when it comes to interviewing unless they specifically say that they could help you elsewhere in the company. I did have one interview once with a group of other candidates and the hiring managers did assure me that they would be more than happy to help us send our resume elsewhere in the company.

#### 6) Don't ask about how you did during the interview.

Always do your best. How you do in the interview is something that the hiring manager is concerned about. It's like an exam during school. Once you've submitted your exam, wondering about how you did will change the result of your efforts.

#### 7) "Are there a lot of layoffs?" unless there is a known history in the company for frequent layoffs.

People reading this might have a different opinion on this and I might see why. It might very well depend on the personality of the hiring manager. I've actually asked this question before with my company because I remembered hearing about layoffs from my internship days at the same company (thankfully, the time after my internship, this has changed). The manager actually didn't mind me asking the question and they assured me that their particular organization has never experienced layoffs compared to the rest of the company. I don't think it's a selfish question since it shows that you are secure.

#### 8) Don't ask anything political.

For instance, don't ask how the government has affected the company in any way like, "How much of an impact has *XYZ* policies affected how the company operates?" It's not your concern how it affects your company unless the position is directly affected by these political policies.

---

I can't think of anymore questions but generally you should avoid questions that you would never want to ask yourself if you put yourself in the shoes of the hiring manager.